# how to pass the multiple parameter in URL

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to pass the two parameter in the URL in post method to a http connection but not getting any success can any one help me out the code is

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // add request header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    JsonObject requestData = new JsonObject();
    requestData.addProperty("email", "nitin@eye-watch.in");
    requestData.addProperty("name", "nitin malik");
    requestData.addProperty("phone_no", "9540825737");

    File fileToUpload = new File("/home/nitin/Desktop/clientdcs.jpg");

    String urlParameters = "form=" + requestData.toString() + "&file=" + fileToUpload;

    // Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

Comment: Remember to [form-encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) your data: `String urlParameters = "form=" + URLEncoder.encode(requestData.toString(), "UTF-8") + "&file=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileToUpload, "UTF-8");`

Comment: URLEncoder.encode(fileToUpload, "UTF-8"); this is not supported for file.

Comment: Change it to `URLEncoder.encode(fileToUpload.toString(), "UTF-8")`.

Comment: how to access the urlParameters in request objcet in HttpServlet, by doing URLEncoder.encode(fileToUpload.toString(), "UTF-8") file is now in string format.to get real file i have to decode the file.or servlet 3.0 is good for this?

Comment: by doing this i am able to send data in request               String urlParameters = "form=" + URLEncoder.encode(mainData.toString(),"UTF-8") + "&file=" +URLEncoder.encode(fileToUpload.toString(),"UTF-8");    but when i try to get on servlet by String ufl = request.getParameter("file"); that time /home/nitin/Desktop/clientdcs.jpg how to conert in in to file    
  /*String urlParameters = "form=" + URLEncoder.encode(mainData.toString(),"UTF-8") + "&file=";*/

  // Send post request
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
  wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
  wr.flush();

Comment: If you want to send the *contents* of the file, you probably should be using [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) for your Content-Type.  I recommend using JavaMail, specifically `new MimeMultipart("form-data")` and MimeBodyPart.attachFile.  Or, if you know your file is a text file, you can try `URLEncoder.encode(new String(Files.readAllBytes(fileToUpload.toPath()), "UTF-8"), "UTF-8");`.

Comment: if i am using multipart/form-data than how to access the form and file in servlet

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send the contents of a file, you usually want to use [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) for your Content-Type.

Building a multipart/form-data message can be done using the JavaMail library:

```
MimeBodyPart formPart = new MimeBodyPart();
formPart.setContent(
    URLEncoder.encode(requestData.toString(), "UTF-8"),
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
formPart.setDisposition("form-data; name=\"form\"");

MimeBodyPart filePart = new MimeBodyPart();
filePart.attachFile(fileToUpload);
ContentDisposition disposition = new ContentDisposition("form-data");
disposition.getParameterList().set("name", "file");
disposition.getParameterList().set("filename", fileToUpload.toString(), "UTF-8");
filePart.setDisposition(disposition.toString());

MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("form-data");
multipart.addBodyPart(formPart);
multipart.addBodyPart(filePart);

try (OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream()) {
    multipart.writeTo(out);
}
```

A Servlet can read the form data using the `getPart` method of HttpServletRequest:

```
Part formPart = request.getPart("form");
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) formPart.getSize());
try (ReadableByteChannel in =
        Channels.newChannel(formPart.getInputStream()) {
    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        in.read(buffer);
    }
}
String encoded = new String(buffer.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String form = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");

Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
File sentFile = new File(filePart.getName());
File file = new File(downloadDirectory, sentFile.getName());
filePart.write(file.toString());
```

Comment: tanks for your support